# Como inserir e customizar tooltips na imagem usando map e area tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Pessoal estou tentando criar em uma imagem de um produto vários pontos de interesse, quando a pessoa clicar em um desses pontos se abrirá uma tooltip com as informações necessárias.

Eu já criei as coordenadas usando uma ferramente online (https://www.image-map.net/) e até aí tudo bem, tudo funcionando, quando eu clico abre o link ou aparece o title que eu setei. Só que eu quero que fique em "ícone" de (+) em cada área de interesse e isso eu não sei fazer.

Meu código está assim até agora:

```html
<img src="imagem-que-estou-usando.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
  <area target="_blank" alt="Alt da Imagem" href="http://google.com" coords="629,336,56" shape="circle" title="Title quando hover">
</map>
```

Tem algum modo que eu possa inserir tais customizações na area? E como eu triggo isso com o click para abrir a tooltip? Eu estava pensando em fazer usando jQeury, mas estou aberto a sugestões!

Um exemplo de como eu queria é este:
https://hypebeast.com/2016/1/essentials-dolly-cohen-celebrity-grill-maker

Obrigado!

Comment: Cara o exemplo que vc mandou não vai funcionar bem com as coordenadas geradas pela ferramenta que vc usou. Use esse link para pegar os pontos de referencia em %, e lá construa seu Tooltip com uma Div e um (+) dentro... https://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/

Comment: Muito obrigado hugo! Agora deu certo, me salvou aqui! :)